# Add similar alphanumeric elements from list python

Tags: python, list

I have two list `A = ['1a', '3c']` and `B = ['2a', '1b']`. I want to add the 
strings which ends with same character and update the contents of A like shown below:

Final result to be: `A = ['3a', '3c']`. Below is my code:

```
for x, y in enumerate(A):
        # gets the indices of B which has same end character
        l = [B.index(i) for i in B if y[1] in i]
```

Comment: That's a strange choice of a data structure if you need to perform operations like this. How about having a map from character to counts: `A = {"a":1, "c":3}`. Then you can add `A["a"] += B["a"]` (add some iteration logic over `A.keys()`, of course).

Comment: @Pavel sorry but I can't change the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
A = ['1a', '3c'] 
B = ['2a', '1b']
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(A, B)):
  if x[-1] == y[-1]:
    A[i] = str(int(x[0])+int(y[0])) + x[-1]
print A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to split the int from the chars, and then sum if they are equals, with list comp it would be (considering the len of two lists are equals):

import re

```
A = ['1a', '3c', "2b"]
B = ['2a', '1b', "4c"]

def splitNum(x):
  return list(filter(None, re.split(r'(\d+)', x)))

A = [str(int(splitNum(x)[0]) + int(splitNum(y)[0])) + (splitNum(x)[1]) for x in A for y in B if splitNum(x)[1] == splitNum(y)[1]]

print(A)

 => ['3a', '7c', '3b']
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Although, I don't want to create a new list instead want to update list A?